# How to fix remove duplicate from lists with lambda and condition

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, duplicates, java-stream

I want to know why returned list included "1"

```
List<Integer> a= Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List<Integer> b=Arrays.asList(1,7,8,9,10);

a.stream().filter(first -> (b.stream().anyMatch(second -> first.compareTo(second)!=0)))
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original solution was looking for numbers in set `a` which are different to at least one number in set `b`.

In the case of 1, it is different from 7, and is thus a match.

You were probably, in this case, looking for `noneMatch` instead:

```
a.stream().filter(first -> (b.stream().noneMatch(first::equals)))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

(Of course, using `contains` is easier on this occasion anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for :

```
a.stream().filter(first -> !b.contains(first)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here, the resulting stream will contain only values that are not present in list `b`.

Comment: @mehranarbabian Also consider using a `Set` for `b` to improve performance.

Comment: @Glains If the collection is of size 5, it won't make any meaningful difference.

Comment: @JoeC That is true, but it´s always good to mention important things that might be relevant in the future. Thanks for the point tough!